# LocalStorage React useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy teniendo el siguiente problema, resulta que al guardar favoritos al localstorage va bien, el problema lo tengo cuando estoy leyendo esa data del local, me la elimina de igual manera al refrescar, lo que hacia es pasarle un tercer argumento al reducer y retornaba el localStorage.getItem(). Intentando nuevamente, puedo hacer que guarde correctamente, pero a la hora de traer los resultados del localstorage cuando refresco desaparece.

REPO: https://github.com/JonathanAGonzalez/rickandmorty

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favorites.favorites));
  }, [favorites]);


    const initialState = {
  favorites: [],
};

  const [favorites, dispatch] = useReducer(favoriteReducer, initialState);

 useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favorites.favorites));
  }, [favorites]);
```

Reducer

```
export const favoriteReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_FAVORITE":
      return {
        ...state,
        favorites: [...state.favorites, action.payload],
      };

    case "REMOVE_FROM_FAVORITE":
      return {
        ...state,
        favorites: [
          ...state.favorites.filter((favorite) => favorite !== action.payload),
        ],
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Dispatch

```
const handleFavorite = (favorite) => {
    dispatch({
      type: !!isCharacterInFavorites(favorite)
        ? "REMOVE_FROM_FAVORITE"
        : "ADD_TO_FAVORITE",
      payload: favorite,
    });
  };
```

Alguien tiene alguna idea como guardar en el localStorage usando Reducer?.

Comment: Si pudieras agregar la función `reducer` y también cómo estas llamando a `dispatch`, saludos.

Comment: Si, perdon, ahí esta. Gracias

Comment: Estoy tratando de emular la situación, mientras tanto [esta publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64547044/persist-localstorage-with-usereducer) te puede ser de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias!, voy a revisarlo y trataré de implementarlo. Adjunto el link al repo por si sirve también. Gracias